# beautifulSoap scraping error NameError: name 'soup' is not defined

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am starting with web-scraping, and I am getting a error:

I am getting this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrape.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(str(parsePrice()))
  File "scrape.py", line 9, in parsePrice
    price=soup.find('span', {'class': 'Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)'}).text
NameError: name 'soup' is not defined
```

Thats my code scrape.py:

```
import bs4
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def parsePrice():
    r=requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FB?p=FB')
    soap=bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'xml')

    price=soup.find('span', {'class': 'Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)'}).text
    return price

while True:
    print('The current price is: ')
    print(str(parsePrice()))
```

Comment: just change `soap=bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'xml')` to `soap= BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'xml')` and change `soup.find` to `soap.find` since you already defined it with `soap`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script still won't work even if you fix the `soup` issue because this is not where you wanna use `xml` parser. You should go with `html.parser` or `lxml` or `html5lib` instead. Moreover, you used compound classes which may lead you to any error in near future. However, this is something I would do:

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FB?p=FB'

def parsePrice(url):
    r = requests.get(url,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
    price = soup.find("span",class_="Mb(-4px)").text
    return price

while True:
    print('The current price is:',parsePrice(link))
    time.sleep(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change line

```
soap=bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'xml')
```

to

```
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'xml')
```

Comment: @KunduK are you really didn't realized this part of `bs4.BeautifulSoup` too ?

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη : I was just encouraging the new contributor.